# Algorithm to remove and shift elements in an array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am struggling to come up with a technique to achieve following:

Example:
Input:

```
a[] = [0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0]

Array a has 8 entries. Each entry will have either 0 or 1.
```

Output:

```
output = [1 3 5 6 0 2 4 7]

Output will have the indices of all the 1s first and then all the zeros.
```

Any recommendation? I am not an algo expert. I have tried solving it using heap/tree but struggling to come up with something with time complexity O(log2(N)).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything fancy; just do two passes over the input array, and keep track of where you are in each array.

For example:

```java
int[] output = new int[input.length];
int outputIndex = 0;
for (int inputIndex = 0; inputIndex < a.length; ++inputIndex) {
    if (input[inputIndex] == 1) {
        output[outputIndex] = inputIndex;
        ++outputIndex;
    }
}
for (int inputIndex = 0; inputIndex < a.length; ++inputIndex) {
    if (input[inputIndex] == 0) {
        output[outputIndex] = inputIndex;
        ++outputIndex;
    }
}
```

---

> […] struggling to come up with something with time complexity O(log2(N)).

Right — since you need to read all *N* input elements in order to find out where the 1s are, and you need to write all *N* output elements, it's not possible to do better than *O*(*N*).

Comment: Yea I am struggling because I thought this can be done with O(logN). Initially I thought I can create a balanced binary tree with the indices of input array. Then sort it based on value in each index (1 or 0)...

Comment: @newbie That would require iterating through the entire array, which would still leave it at O(n).